# Specify build directory path for sphinx output?

Tags: build, directory, python-sphinx

Is it possible to redefine where sphinx outputs the build files? I want to run a local server (for testing purposes as the documentation is later hosted anyway) and implement some webhook APIs which obviously don't work if I don't have a responding server. So I installed apache and now I want to build to C:/Apache24/htdocs directly. Can I do this?

Comment: See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html

Comment: Consider using the Sphinx extension https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autobuild/ for live reload as you edit. Much better than `make build`, then manually refresh the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did was just edit the make.bat file in the docs directory (or where your doc is installed):

```
set BUILDDIR=your/path/to/build
```

Answer (score 0):

With your Sphinx project in `docs`:

`sphinx-build docs build`

See: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html.